# Error in building point cloud using PointCloud2

Tags: rviz, pcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to build a point cloud using pcl function as in the code. It seems to work as the point cloud gets accumulated over time as I monitor ROS_INFO output from rxconsole. The variable "cloud" in the code is a cloud that is gathered over time while "c_tmp" is a temporary cloud that is stored in.

The problem I'm currently having is that I couldn't be able to visualize it via rviz. As I click on the /cloud topic, it warns that "No messages received". As for /c_tmp topic, no surprise, it just works out the box. Any idea, how do I fix this? Is the point cloud building correctly coded?

```
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud; //Class variable

//    In a callback function
{
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 c_tmp;

static tf::TransformBroadcaster tfb;
tf::Transform xform;
xform.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(pose3D_LDD.pose.position.x, pose3D_LDD.pose.position.y, pose3D_LDD.pose.position.z));
xform.setRotation(tf::Quaternion(pose3D_LDD.pose.orientation.x, pose3D_LDD.pose.orientation.y, pose3D_LDD.pose.orientation.z, pose3D_LDD.pose.orientation.w));
tfb.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(xform, ros::Time(pose3D_LDD.header.stamp), "base_link", "laser"));
tfListener_.waitForTransform("base_link", "laser", previous_scan_.header.stamp, ros::Duration(1.0));

try
{
    projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("base_link", previous_scan_, c_tmp, tfListener_);

    if (!initialized_cloud_)
    {
        cloud = c_tmp;
        initialized_cloud_ = true;
    }
    else
    {
         pcl::concatenatePointCloud(cloud, c_tmp, cloud);

         ROS_INFO("From c_tmp: Got cloud with %u of width and %u of height", c_tmp.width, c_tmp.height);
         ROS_INFO("From cloud: Got cloud with %u of width and %u of height", cloud.width, cloud.height);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
    if (!initialized_cloud_)
    {
        cloud = c_tmp;
        initialized_cloud_ = true;
    }
    else
    {
        pcl::concatenatePointCloud(cloud, c_tmp, temp_cloud);
        cloud = temp_cloud;

        ROS_INFO("From c_tmp: Got cloud with %u of width and %u of height", c_tmp.width, c_tmp.height);
        ROS_INFO("From cloud: Got cloud with %u of width and %u of height", cloud.width, cloud.height);
          }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12829/error-in-building-point-cloud-using-pointcloud2/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-01-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-31**:
I'm not really sure, it is right or not.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-31**:
See here (http://www.ros.org/doc/diamondback/api/pcl/html/io_8cpp_source.html), this one not actually a documentation but would suffice to refer I think. Actually that function I just type pcl:: and with my autocompletion, then i guess the function itself should be self-explanatory.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-31**:
Can you point me to the documentation on pcl::concatenatePointCloud()? I can't find it anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is just solved. The lesson learned is the cloud itself has to be defined its frame. So, I define it in my launch file using static_transform_publisher package.

---

Originally posted by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) with karma: 1053 on 2012-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the documentation for `pcl::concatenatePointCloud()` is correct, you cannot provide cloud as a `const` input and also as the output. You must provide a third cloud to be filled in the function. Then, you can set cloud = third_cloud.

```
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 temp_cloud;
pcl::concatenatePointCloud(cloud, c_tmp, temp_cloud);
cloud = temp_cloud;
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-01**:
Yes, it is PointCloud2 not PointCloud i mean..

**Comment by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on 2012-02-01**:
are you sure that you are showing Pointcloud2 type message  in rviz?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-01**:
Yes, I've checked from the rxconsole and rostopic echo /cloud, it seems messages always come but, in rviz, they don't.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-02-01**:
Have you check that this callback is actually be called 100 times? If the incoming message is not being received, then the output message won't be published.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-01**:
Yes I do have, I set it like this "point_cloud_publisher_ = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("/cloud", 100);
"point_cloud_publisher_.publish(cloud);"

**Comment by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on 2012-02-01**:
It may be a silly question... But, Are you actually publishing the messages?? have you a publisher like ros::Publisher pub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("cloud", 100); and then do pub.publish(cloud);

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-31**:
By the way, at the moment, the best case I have is getting 2 messages received in rviz, but it's still problematic as I expect to get more than 100 messages at least.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-31**:
Yes, I agree with you. I really overlooked it, 1st and 2nd arguments are constant. I rewrite it and run, but still having the same problem.